# Self-Sizing TableView Cells based on two subview's height

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitableviewautomaticdimension

**TableView Description**
`tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
 tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60.0`

**Cell Description**
I have a cell with 2 Labels(Title, Description) inside a ContainerView and 1 ImageView as below. Cell height will vary based on Description Label’s content.
 [Contraints of all views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyZMa.png)

**There are two cases that I should handle**

1. ContainerView.height greater than (ImageView.height + ImageView.Top + ImageView.Bottom). Here cell's height will be based on ContainerView.height
2. ContainerView height less than (ImageView.height + ImageView.Top + ImageView.Bottom). Here I expect Cell should consider (ImageView.height + ImageView.Top + ImageView.Bottom) as the height and make ContainerView vertically centre to Cell.
   [Expected Result in both the cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjDJW.png)

**Problem**
If I set constraints for 1st case then 2nd case is not working and vice versa (I’m aware that by removing ContrainerView.Top, Bottom and making it Vertically Centre to SuperView case 2 result can be achieved)

Is there a way to achieve expected result in both the cases by using same set of IB constraints and UITableViewAutomaticDimension?

Comment: What is the issue if you do `Vertically Centre to SuperView` ??

Comment: Use `heightForRow` and `estimatedheightfor`. It automatically adjust your cell according to your container size. I think thats what you want.

Comment: @agent_stack If I use that constraint, then _Case 1_ would fail. For Instance, When Description Label's content is more than 3 lines, text will be cutoff

Answer (score 0):

Give fixed height and width to the image view . Otherwise let the tableViewCell know the top and bottom of the imageview. So that it can calculate the correct cell height

Answer (score 0):

Use these delegates,

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     return 100; // height of default cell
 }

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

> Edit

Try this one.

Your view hierarchy should be like this

[image]

**ImageView Constraints**

[image]

Add a view and put both labels into it.

**Label Container contraints**

[image]

**Label Title constraint**

[image]

**Label Description constraint**

[image]

> **Edit Output**

[image]

Comment: Yeah. I'm doing that. Actually I made _Case 1_ to work with the these [constraint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyZMa.png) and as I've mention in **Problem**, I can add different constraints and make _Case 2_ work but I want to know If I can add any constraints so that both the cases would work.

Comment: @Shyam Check Edit

Comment: @Shyam If you still facing any issue, I added output of my edit answer. Hope now you achieve your requirement. If still you have any doubt then let me know.

Comment: Thanks for ur time :) Your answer is almost correct, still it is not exactly as my [expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjDJW.png), If you look closely, in Case 2 **ContainerView's height is less than ImageView's Height** and ContainerView is Vertically Centered. Basically this is my issue, Self-Sizing a Cell based on 1 subview's height is straight forward but in my case it should be based on 2 subview's height (Using ContainerView's height if it is more than ImageView's height and vise versa)

Comment: @Shyam Thats why I added a view for labels which handle this problem what you mentained above. You need to set minimum height.

Comment: 'view for labels', I'm calling that view as 'ContainerView' from the start. Please look at [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-fyairwDktdenFFLV9lcGZiYTA/view), hope I have pointed out the exact issue.

Comment: @Shyam Dont be confused, check this output https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAg6j.png which is updated on my above answer as per your requirement. I removed the output which you mentained  in above comment so that you know right output.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you are using self-sizing cells:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html

Make Top and Bottom constraints for both image view and the container view to the edges of the cell and make them `>=`.

Alternatively, you could try Horizontal Stack View and make rigid (highest priorities) constraints to each edge of the cell.